# Building a (html) table using XML data and XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following XML (slightly simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
    <DataItem>
        <Name>Name1</Name>
        <Use>a</Use>
        <Use>b</Use>
        <Use>c</Use>
        <Use>d</Use>
        <Use>e</Use>
        <DataItem>
            <Name>Item2</Name>
            <Use>a</Use>
            <Use>c</Use>
            <Use>d</Use>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem>
            <Name>Item3</Name>
            <Use>a</Use>
            <Use>b</Use>
            <Use>e</Use>
            <DataItem>
                <Name>Whatever</Name>
                <Use>a</Use>
                <Use>b</Use>
                <Use>d</Use>
            </DataItem>
        </DataItem>
    </DataItem>
</Message>
```

As you see, the structure is recursive. Now what I need to accomplish is create a table like so:

| Item | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | x | x | x | x | x |
| Item2 | x |  | x | x |  |
| Item3 | x | x |  |  | x |
| Whatever | x | x |  | x |  |

Now setting up the header is easy, I can just loop through all the values of the first data item (which always contains all the options). I can also populate the first column with the names. But what I cannot wrap my head around is how to fill the rest of the table. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Message">
    <xsl:variable name="col" select="DataItem[1]/Use" />
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <!-- header -->
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$col">
                        <th>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </th>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
                <!-- data -->
                <xsl:for-each select="//DataItem">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                        </td>
                        <xsl:variable name="row" select="Use" />
                        <xsl:for-each select="$col">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:if test=". = $row">x</xsl:if>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. So anoyingly simple. I was so so so close myself, but couldn't quite get it. This works perfectly!